# Getting av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken Pipe after a while

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm getting "av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipe" every time I try to stream WITH audio, no matter the input source. The error does not come up instantly, but rather sporadically. I try to use FFMPEG from within AutoHotkey, so when users start the AHK Script their webcam with sound will automatically be streamed to a central RTSP-Proxy.

> Version: ffmpeg-2022-11-23-git-c8e9cc8d20-full_build

> OS : Win 10 64bit 22H2 19045.2251

For testing, I tried to stream in a local environment from one PC to another directly connected via ethernet to the same switch, so there should be no issues at play.

I tried the following command, executed from a .BAT, in the CommandLine and from within a CommandLine embedded in Autohotkey.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel 56 -hide_banner -f dshow -i audio="VoiceMeeter Output (VB-Audio VoiceMeeter VAIO)" -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://10.18.7.103:8554/live
```

Tracelog: https://pastebin.com/ABV049BT

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is caused because the rtsp server you are streaming to closed the connection. like timeout error.

I once had faced the issue. In my case, if the stream is paused for some period of time, the server would close the connection. To avoid, it you can transmit silence audio packets instead of transmitting nothing at all.